# Svelte head title suffix

Tags: javascript, dom, svelte, svelte-component, svelte-3

I want to add a head title suffix like `- mywebsite` on each Svelte page.

I'm struggling finding how to do it with ease and simplicity.

On the svelte website source, we can see they do it manually: https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/blob/1273f978084aaf4d7c697b2fb456314839c3c90d/site/src/routes/docs/index.svelte#L15

I started creating a component like this:

```
<script>
  export let title = false;
</script>

<svelte:head>
  <title>
    {#if title}
      {title} • WebSite
    {:else}
      Website • Home suffix
    {/if}
  </title>
</svelte:head>
```

But:

- I have a `<title> can only contain text and {tags}svelte(illegal-structure)` error
- I'm not sure it's the easiest way.

How can an achieve what I want to do?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since `<title>` only can contain text or `{tags}` you could compute the document title with the ternary operator.

**Example**

```html
<script>
  export let title = false;
</script>

<svelte:head>
  <title>{title ? `${title} • WebSite` : 'Website • Home suffix'}</title>
</svelte:head>
```

Comment: So create a title component to import on every page is the best solution? Nothing more simple/buit-in?

Comment: If you're making an SPA or using Sapper then you can keep the `<svelte:head>` in your top component and update it programmatically

Comment: @BennyHinrichs are you suggesting to create a `title.js` file to make it? In that case, it is not better than creating a component, am I wrong?

Comment: In Sapper, you would just put the title logic in your `_layout.svelte` file. See the [docs](https://sapper.svelte.dev/docs#Layouts) and an example in [sapper-template](https://github.com/sveltejs/sapper-template/blob/master/src/routes/_layout.svelte).

Answer (score 6):

While using a ternary **inside** of the markup works just fine, reactivity statements may help clean it up:

```xml
<script>
  export let title = false;

  $: fullTitle = title 
        ? `${title} • WebSite` 
        : 'Website • Home suffix';
</script>

<svelte:head>
  <title>{fullTitle}</title>
</svelte:head>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also use small store for this.
Here you can find REPL example:
https://svelte.dev/repl/b604a75a8a344527a39f10cab7b7ee66?version=3.32.0

```js
import { writable } from 'svelte/store';

function createTitle() {
    const {subscribe, set, update} = writable('');
    
    return {
        subscribe,
        set: (value) => {
            set(`${value} • WebSite`)
        },
        clear: () => {
            set('Website • Home suffix');
        }
    }
}

export const title = createTitle();
```

Then when you want set new title you can use:

```
title.set('page title')
```

Store will add suffix automatically...

If you want display main title call:

```
title.reset()
```